# Javascript returning Nan when all the variables are numbers?

Tags: javascript, css, string, html, variables

My js is returning NaN after "your total is." But I don't have the slightest idea as to why. I think I have all my variables properly declared; is there another reason why this is happening?

Here's my code below. Everything else in the js seems to be working fine.

```js
function book() {
  var city = document.getElementsByName('city').value;
  var hotel = document.getElementsByName('hotel').value;
  var people = document.getElementsByName('numtravel').value;
  var days = document.getElementsByName('numdays').value;
  var wifi;
    if ( document.getElementsByName('wifi').checked = false)
    wifi = 0;
    if ( document.getElementsByName('wifi').checked = true)
    wifi = 10;
  var seat;
    if ( document.getElementsByName('sausage').checked = false) seat = 0;
    if ( document.getElementsByName('sausage').checked = true) seat = 20;
  var meal = document.getElementById('meal').value;
  var price1 = people * meal;
  var price2 = people * seat;
  var price3 = hotel * days;

  document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = 'Your total is ' + ( city + price3 + wifi + price1 + price2 );

  return false;
}

/*   Total eggs, man. ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°) */
```

```css
#main_content
        {
            background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-align: center;
            border: 5px dotted lightblue
        } 


body    {
            background-color: lightgrey;
        }
#content

        {
            background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-align: center;
            border: 5px dotted lightblue
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Make a Reservation!</title>
    <script src="new.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="new.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main_content">
      <a href = "file:///Users/abbeylaxgang/Desktop/Bus/busline_home.htm">Home</a>
      <br>
      <a href = "file:///Users/abbeylaxgang/Desktop/Bus/busline_contact.htm">Contact Us</a>
      <br>
      <a href = "file:///Users/abbeylaxgang/Desktop/Bus/busline_new.htm">Make a Reservation</a>
      <br>
      <a href = "file:///Users/abbeylaxgang/Desktop/Bus/busline_email.htm">Join Our Email List</a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="content">
      <div id="reservation">
        <h2> Make a Reservation!</h2>
        <p> First Name: <input type="text" id="first" name="FirstName"/></p>
        <p> Last Name: <input type="text" id="last" name="LastName"/></p>
        <h4>
          <p> Where is your arrival city?</p>
        </h4>
        <p> St. Louis ($40) <input type="radio" value="40" name="city" /></p>
        <p> Milwaukee ($20) <input type="radio" value="20" name="city"/></p>
        <p> Detroit ($35) <input type="radio" value="35" name="city"/></p>
        <h4><p>Hotel Choice?</p></h4>
        <p> Economy ($50/day) <input type="radio" value="50" name='hotel'/></p>
        <p> Standard ($70/day) <input type="radio" value="70" name='hotel'/></p>
        <p> Upscale ($120/day) <input type="radio" value="120" name="hotel"/></p>
        <h4> Amount of travelers? </h4>
        <select id="travelers" name="numtravel">
          <option value="1"> 1 </option>
          <option value="2"> 2 </option>
          <option value="3"> 3 </option>
          <option value="4"> 4 </option>
          <option value="5"> 5 </option>
          <option value="6"> 6 </option>
        </select>
        <h4> Amount of days? </h4>
        <select id="days" name="numdays">
          <option value="2"> 2 </option>
          <option value="3"> 3 </option>
          <option value="4"> 4 </option>
          <option value="5"> 5 </option>
          <option value="6"> 6 </option>
          <option value="7"> 7 </option>
        </select>
        <h4> Extra emenities: </h4>
        <p> Wifi ($10) <input type="checkbox" value='20' name="wifi"></p>
        <p> Fully-Reclining Seat ($20) <input type="checkbox" name="sausage" value='30'></p>
        <h4> Meal choice? </h4>
        <select id="meal" name="meal">
          <option value="0"> None </option>
          <option value="5"> Snack ($5) </option>
          <option value="10"> Full Meal ($10) </option>
        </select>
        <h3> <p> Special Requests?</p> </h3>
        <p> <textarea name="txtRequests" col="25" rows="5" style='width:300px;resize:vertical;'> </textarea></p>
        <p> <button onclick="book()">Book your Trip!</button></p>
        <br>
      </div>
      <h1 id="p1"> </h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: no, `element.value` is a string - try `parseFloat(element.value)` - i.e. `var city = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName('city').value);`

Comment: `document.getElementsByName('city').value` for example isn't a number

Comment: A single `=` is assignment, so `if ( document.getElementsByName('sausage').checked = false)` will uncheck the box. `= true` will check it. Use `!x` to get `true` when `x` is `false`, and just write `x` to get `true` when `x` is `true`.

Comment: Also please read the help center before posting. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert your values to the correct datatype before performing any arithmetic opetraion

```
var days = document.getElementById('numdays').value;
```

should be

```
var days = parseInt(document.getElementById('numdays').value); //convert to integer
if(isNaN(days)) {
    alert("Days must be a valid number");
    return;
}
```

Do this for all other values

You can then do days * people, etc

Comment: *"You have to convert your values to the correct datatype before performing any arithmetic opetraion"* - Except that several operators automatically convert strings to numbers, e.g., `*`, `-`, `/`, so you don't necessarily *have to* convert the values first.

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementsByName returns an array, so you need to set [0].

I suggest just use document.querySelector.

and notice that the value of a node is a string, not a number. you should convert it.

and don't use one "=" in an "if"

here is my code:

```
function book() {
    var city = +(document.querySelector("[name='city']:checked") || { value: 0 }).value;
    console.log("city", city);
    var hotel = +(document.querySelector("[name='hotel']:checked") || { value: 0 }).value;
    console.log("hotel", hotel);
    var people = +document.querySelector("[name='numtravel']").value;
    console.log("people", people);
    var days = +document.querySelector("[name='numdays']").value;
    console.log("days", days);
    var wifi;
    if (document.getElementsByName('wifi')[0].checked === false) wifi = 0;
    if (document.getElementsByName('wifi')[0].checked === true) wifi = 10;
    console.log("wifi", wifi);
    var seat;
    if (document.getElementsByName('sausage')[0].checked === false) seat = 0;
    if (document.getElementsByName('sausage')[0].checked === true) seat = 20;
    console.log("seat", seat);
    var meal = +document.getElementById('meal').value;
    console.log("meal", meal);
    console.log(people, meal, seat, days);
    var price1 = people * meal;
    var price2 = people * seat;
    var price3 = hotel * days;

    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = 'Your total is ' + (city + price3 + wifi + price1 + price2);

    return false;
}
```